# Entityframework ObjectContext instance has been disposed in certain location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, objectdisposedexception

I'm getting the exception:

"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

Only when I try to add the object or some properties of that object to `@Html.ActionLink`.

I have reviewed my code couple of times and can't find anything unusual any suggestions on what might be causing this exception?

Thank you!

*UserManagerResult.cs*

```
public class UserManagerResult {
    public bool Success{get; set;}
    public string ErrorMessage{get; set;}
    public Account User{get; set;}
    public List <Account> UserList{get;}
    public UserManagerResult() {
        Success = false;
        UserList = new List <Account>();
    }

}
```

*UserManager.cs*

```
    public static UserManagerResult GetUserList() {
        UserManagerResult userManagerResult = new UserManagerResult();
        try {
            using (AlenMotorsDbEntities alenMotorsDbEntities = new AlenMotorsDbEntities()) {
                foreach (Account account in alenMotorsDbEntities.Accounts.ToList()) {
                    userManagerResult.UserList.Add(account);
                }
                return userManagerResult;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            userManagerResult.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            return userManagerResult;
        }
    }
```

*DeveloperViewModel.cs*

```
public class DeveloperViewModel {
    [Display(Name = "New Role")]
    public string NewRole{get; set;}
    [Display(Name = "Remove Role")]
    public List <SelectListItem> RoleList{get; set;}
    [Display(Name = "User list")]
    public List <Account> UserList{get; set;}
}
```

*UserManagerController.cs*

```
 public ActionResult Developer(DeveloperViewModel model) {
        UserManagerResult getUserList = UserManager.GetUserList();
        model.UserList = getUserList.UserList.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

*The view I'm using*

```
                 @{
                foreach (Account account in Model.UserList.ToList()) {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">--</th>
                        <td>@account.Email</td>
                        <td>@account.LastName</td>
                        <td>@account.FirstName</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", account)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
```

Comment: Show me your Account entity. It's probably lazy loading in action. Convert your `account` in `userManagerResult.UserList.Add(account);` to some projection

Comment: I have worked around the issue by projection the needed information from Account to a new class AccountViewModel, to expose the view only the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

In your GetUserList(), try this:

```
 foreach (Account account in alenMotorsDbEntities.Accounts.Include(i=>i.YourOtherEntity).Include(i=>i.AnotherEntity).ToList())
```

And keep adding all related entities that is relevant.

Comment: I have tried using include but I don't have what to include.. because I want the entire alenMotorsDbEntities.Accounts to List <Accounts>  http://tiny.cc/36628x